# can we pass parameter in computed property in swift?

Tags: swift, xcode

```
class a{
    var i:Int{
        return 10
    }
}
```

in this code, I want to pass parameter in "i" variable and they return this parameter. is this possible in swift?

Comment: Do you mean like this?  

let xy = { (x: Int, y:Int) -> Int! in
        return x * y
}

Comment: I don't understand, can you give an example code what you want to achieve?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, you can't.

To pass one or multiple parameters you have to use a function / method.

However you can assign a closure to a variable.

Comment: Could you provide an example code?
I'm stuck with
var kTabs: CGFloat = ((Int?) -> CGFloat) { myInt in
        return 0.0
}

Answer (score 5):

You can do something like this:

```
var variable: (Int) -> Int {
    { input in
        input * 10
    }
}

print(variable(1))   // prints 10
print(variable(5))   // prints 50
print(variable(10))  // prints 100
```

Comment: How to set a default value for `input`?

Answer (score 2):

As @vadian already said, you can't.
But if you want to do some calculation when setting `i` you could adjust the `setter`:

```
class a {
    private var _i: Int = 0

    var i: Int {
        set {
            _i = newValue + 5 // or whatever you want
        }

        get {
            return _i
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, based on Swift 4 you declare a gettable variable and you don't define it as a settable variable, so you cant assign value to var i.

you can use this syntax to assign variable from outside the class:

```
class a {
    var i: Int = 10 // define var as settable and gettable properties
}
```